# Cambiar el bg color dentro de un componente React

Tags: reactjs

estoy haciendo un map que devuelve atributos de un objeto. Cada iteracion crea un elemente

quiero colocar en cada iteracion un bgcolor diferente dependiendo si la propiedad id es par o impar. ¿por donde debo encarar? gracias

Comment: En el map puedes acceder al index, solo es que revises si es par o no y segun eso pones las propiedades del componente

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Muestra el codigo y muestra lo que has intentado. Lo que pides es sencillo pero en esta comunida se exige que intentes tu inicialmente que detectes allí donde està fallando tu código, y, cuando no eres capaz de resolver el error, venir aquí a pedir ayuda.

(*) dentro del map

```
// tu map tiene que tener algo parecido a esto

cosa.map((objeto, indice) => (
    <div style={backgroundColor: indice %2 === 0 ? 'azul' : 'rojo' }>hola</div>
))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy usando la libreria chakra para dar estilos. Intentare incluir el codigo .

Comment: Funciono, excelente! mil graicas ferter3006

Comment: Perfecto entonces! Marcala como respuesta correcta así se cierra la pregunta. Un saludo.